# Tumblr meta tag "select" content to be "if"?

Tags: html, tumblr, meta-tags

Tumblr meta tags help a lot with making theme, and I recently found out about "select" meta tag and I want to use it now to make it easy to change post width.

```
<meta name="select:post width" content="400" title="400px">
<meta name="select:post width" content="250" title="250px">
<meta name="select:post width" content="500" title="500px">
```

However it's not good to me when it comes to setting up Photo, Photoset and Video posts because this doesn't and can't work:

```
{Video-{select:post width}}
```

so I wanted to make {block:ifpostwidth400} thing like you can do with text, e.g.

```
<meta name="text:link1" content="home" />
...
{block:iflink1}
...
{/block:iflink1}
```

but it I can't find a way to make this happen, is it even possible?

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a spec for `select`...

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, but you have to clarify the variable first.

```
{block:ifLink1} {/block:iflink1}
```

would be given value through the following variables...

1st.

```
{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{block:Description}
{/block:Description}
```

2nd.

```
<meta name="if:link1 content=1>
```

3rd. 
below `<style type="text/css"> and {custom CSS}`

you clarify where the variable is used such as 'ids' , and placing them
where you desire.

example:  in the `<body> </body>` you put `<div id="links>{block:link1}</div>`

the variable will then have a value...

I hope this helped, it's late but oh well :/

Comment: Hi! I know how to use "if" on Tumblr, but I needed it for `select` option, which is as far as I know still unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't handle the options as ifs. But on my tumblr theme I have an image in the sidebar with the blog title that can be hidden, above the image or below it, and I did it with a select.

Here's the code I used, I hope you can apply it to your problem.

```
<meta name="select:Title position" title="Hidden" content="title-hidden"/>
<meta name="select:Title position" title="Above the image" content="title-above-image"/>
<meta name="select:Title position" title="Under the image" content="title-under-image"/>

<div id="sidebar">
    <h1 id="title1" class="{select:Title Position}">{Title}</h1>
        <a href="/">
            <img src="{image:Sidebar photo}" />
        </a>
    <h1 id="title2" class="{select:Title Position}">{Title}</h1>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.title-hidden{
    display:none;
}

.title-above-image#title2{
    display:none;
}

.title-under-image#title1{
    display:none;
}
```

I don't know if using it on every post affects performance, but here it is anyway.